# Springboot Security + AngularJS Application + Memory and UserService Authentication + Custom Login Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm struggling with my setup for a new application which has the following requirements:

1. Authentication for in memory users (API usage)
2. Authentication for users from UserDetailsService (mysql db)
3. API paths for data fetch and update
4. AngularJS App for MySQL Users

Questions:

1. If I use the custom login page, the user authentication based on the sql users does not work anymore. Default login page works and redirects users to backend page. The problem is, that the username is not passed to the method loadUserByUsername from the UserDetailsService which I added.
2. What do I have to setup, that the authentication for some API Paths is per request (so every request needs to send correct user + password in basic auth) and the users for the backend should have a session which is stored for a defined time

Here is my Setup right now:
User Details Service

```
@Service class AccountDetailsServiceImpl : UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private lateinit var accountRepository: AccountRepository

@Throws(UsernameNotFoundException::class)
override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): AccountDetails {
    val account = accountRepository.getAccountByUsername(username)
    if (account != null) {
        val accountDetails =  AccountDetails(account)
        return accountDetails
    }
    throw UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find account $username")
}}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```html
class MultiHttpSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {   
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var accountDetailsService: UserDetailsService
@Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Autowired
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val daoAuth = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        daoAuth.setUserDetailsService(accountDetailsService)
        daoAuth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuth)

        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(usr1).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw1)).authorities("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER1")
            .and()
            .withUser(usr2).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw2)).authorities("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER2")
            .and()
            .withUser(usr3).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw3)).authorities("ADMIN")
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/app/**",
                "/dist/**",
                "/locales/**",
                "/src/images/**",
                "/src/locales/**",
                "/error",
                "/backend/login",
                "/login" ,
                "/resources/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/backend/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/backend")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...").hasAnyRole("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER1", "EXTERNALSERVICEUSER2")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path..."
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","MANAGER", "USER")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path"
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/adminOnlyPaths../**",
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")

        http.csrf().disable()
    }}
```

```html
class MultiHttpSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {   
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var accountDetailsService: UserDetailsService
@Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Autowired
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val daoAuth = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        daoAuth.setUserDetailsService(accountDetailsService)
        daoAuth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuth)

        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(usr1).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw1)).authorities("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER1")
            .and()
            .withUser(usr2).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw2)).authorities("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER2")
            .and()
            .withUser(usr3).password(passwordEncoder().encode(pw3)).authorities("ADMIN")
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/app/**",
                "/dist/**",
                "/locales/**",
                "/src/images/**",
                "/src/locales/**",
                "/error",
                "/backend/login",
                "/login" ,
                "/resources/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/backend/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/backend")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...").hasAnyRole("EXTERNALSERVICEUSER1", "EXTERNALSERVICEUSER2")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path...",
                "/api/*/path..."
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","MANAGER", "USER")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/path"
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/*/adminOnlyPaths../**",
            ).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")

        http.csrf().disable()
    }}
```

Loginpage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="/css/backendLogin.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="login-main-text">
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="login-form">
      <h3>Login here </h3>
      <hr class="solid-orange">
      <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>User Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller for Security

```html
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class WebController() {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController::class.java)

    @GetMapping("backend")
    fun showBackend(): ModelAndView {
        logger.info("Show page backend")
        return ModelAndView("backend")
    }

    @GetMapping("login")
    fun showLogin(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) error: String?,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) logout: String?
    ): ModelAndView {
        logger.info("Show page backend")
        return ModelAndView("login")
    }

    @GetMapping("em")
    fun showEmergency(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) id: String?
    ): ModelAndView {
        logger.info("Show emergency page $id")
        return ModelAndView("emergency-case")
    }
}
```

The project structure in the resources folder looks like this
-src
--main
--kotlin
--resources
---resources
----css
----images
---static
----angular-app
---templates
----backend.html
----login.html

Comment: you can start by setting up multiple security configurations, one for form login and one for httpbasic https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity-2

Comment: If you read the spring security documentation, you can easy read that when using in memory authentication spring uses the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` to create, manage, and later on fetch users from memory. If you implement a custom `UserDetailsManager` then the inmemory one will not be used. Depending if you divid up your security configuration into 2 configurations you can have a custom `UserDetailsManager`in one conf, and a `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` in the other. If not, you need to write a custom one, that `@Autowires` in `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` and checks users from there too.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/InMemoryUserDetailsManager.html